# Camera in Android app

Tags: android-camera, android-camera2

I am creating an app which required to perform from API 15 to API 23 using camera so what should be the best way to implement camera as camera class is deprecated in API 21 and also android.hardware.camera2 not able to implement on lower version then API 21.

Comment: have a look at textureview http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html

Comment: well i am using textureview http://blog.csdn.net/torvalbill/article/details/40378539 i am using this code but its not working on jellybean app crashes.

Comment: post up your logcat output etc.

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/tszgixk3n/log_error.png check log here.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is something I have taken out of one of my projects, it has had a lot of stuff ripped out for the purpose of putting it on here so you will have to edit it for your needs. It uses the original camera api which is back compatible for your api needs.

```
public class RecordGameKam extends Fragment
        implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private final static String TAG = "CameraRecordTexture";

    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    int numberOfCameras;
    int defaultCameraId;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    protected MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        View rootView = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());

        mTextureView = new TextureView(getActivity());
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        //View parameters-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        rootView.setLayoutParams(params);

        ((ViewGroup) rootView).addView(mTextureView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

        // Find the total number of cameras available
        numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        // Find the ID of the default camera
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }

        try {

            if (mCamera != null) {

                //final Camera.Size previewSize = onMeasure();
                //Camera.Size recorderSize = previewSize;

                final Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                params.setPreviewSize(720, 480);

                mCamera.setParameters(params);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                startContinuousAutoFocus();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Something bad happened
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // Ignored, Camera does all the work for us

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        try {

            if (getActivity().getActionBar() != null) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        // Invoked every time there's a new Camera preview frame
    }

    private boolean setMediaRecorder() throws IllegalStateException {

        try {

            //Create a new instance of MediaRecorder.
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            //Unlock and set camera to Media recorder
            mCamera.unlock();
            mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

            //Configure audio/video input
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            CamcorderProfile profile = null;

            if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P)) {

                profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
            }

            if (profile != null) {

                mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
            }

            //Change oritentation
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90 - 180 + 360);

            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Attempt to prepare the configuration and record video.
        try {

            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camera_pressed);

            mediaRecorder.prepare();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    boolean startContinuousAutoFocus() {

        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();

        assert focusModes != null;
        String CAF_PICTURE = Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE,
                CAF_VIDEO = Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO,
                supportedMode = focusModes
                        .contains(CAF_PICTURE) ? CAF_PICTURE : focusModes
                        .contains(CAF_VIDEO) ? CAF_VIDEO : "";

        if (!supportedMode.equals("")) {

            params.setFocusMode(supportedMode);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

`enter code here`

Comment: thanks i implode in my project and let you know by the way thanks for replying fast.

Comment: you'll need to extract the bare bones of the code there to fit your needs

Comment: But as Camera is deprecated from 21 is this will work over marshmello or lollipop

Comment: it should still work, it just won't be under development. if you want to use the later api you'll have to sacrifice your min supported version. or you could create variants of your app?

Comment: Well i tested app crash on marshmello i think i have to write two code for supporting all api from 15 to 23